# How to fix css tabs which disappear when header title is too long

Tags: html, css

I found this pure CSS Tab on codepen:

http://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/ojtal

Problem is if I put a too long title between `H1` the tabs are disappearing.

```
<html>  
<style>
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato");
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
padding: 20px;
text-align: left;
font-family: Lato;
color: #fff;
background: #9b59b6;
}

h1 {
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: normal;
text-transform: uppercase;
float: left;
margin: 20px 0 100px 10px;
}
h1 span {
font-size: 13px;
display: block;
padding-left: 4px;
}

.tabs {
width: 650px;
float: none;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
margin: 80px 0 0 10px;
text-align: left;
}
.tabs li {
float: left;
display: block;
}
.tabs input[type="radio"] {
position: absolute;
top: -9999px;
left: -9999px;
}
.tabs label {
display: block;
padding: 14px 21px;
border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: normal;
text-transform: uppercase;
background: #8e44ad;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
top: 4px;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.tabs label:hover {
background: #703688;
}
.tabs .tab-content {
z-index: 2;
display: none;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
font-size: 17px;
line-height: 25px;
padding: 25px;
position: absolute;
top: 53px;
left: 0;
background: #612e76;
}
.tabs [id^="tab"]:checked + label {
top: 0;
padding-top: 17px;
background: #612e76;
}
.tabs [id^="tab"]:checked ~ [id^="tab-content"] {
display: block;
}

p.link {
clear: both;
margin: 380px 0 0 15px;
}
p.link a {
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
color: #fff;
padding: 5px 10px;
margin: 0 5px;
background-color: #612e76;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
p.link a:hover {
background-color: #522764;
}

</style>   

<h1>Pure CSS Tabs with LONG TITLE <span>Just CSS, No JS!</span></h1>
<ul class="tabs">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked />
        <label for="tab1">Description</label>
        <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" />
        <label for="tab2">Specification</label>
        <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content">
        <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla?</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<br style="clear: both;" />

<p class="link">See the <a href="http://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/IGxim">3D Box</a> demo!</p>

</html>
```

I tried to add multiple BR this does not fix the problem. How to fix it ?

OK if title is short :
[image]

KO if title is long :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is occurring because of the margin, `margin: 20px 0 100px 10px` on the `h1` element. To resolve the issue, simply remove the `margin-bottom`. If you want the tab elements to be positioned on the right side, you would also need to float them to the right side as well:

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEeGrg)

```
.tabs li {
    float: right;
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to preserve the ordering of the `.tabs li` elements, you could also use:

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVEdqJ)

```
.tabs {
  text-align: right;
}
.tabs li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.tab-content {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZOxgQ

One way of doing it is to add `clear:both` to the tabs.

```
ul.tabs{
clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

problem there is design of this title which is on `float: left;`
and then without `clear: both` like **bhargavponnapalli** said before me is not pushing rest just make them dissapear, then there margins doesn't work also like they should because element on `float: left/right` dont have "real" `height` , thats why there is `.clearfix` on bootstrap or just `clear: both`

you also can just remove `float: left;` to make it as default `float: none;`
like here

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/SzymonDziewonski/pen/YwWzVm)